# QEventLoop in QWebEnginePage.javaScriptConfirm completely skipped

Tags: python, pyqt5, qeventloop

I have a subclass of `QWebEnginePage` where I would like to override the `javaSrciptConfirm` function to create my own popup. It would work by starting a `QEventLoop`, and connecting the `QPushButton.clicked.connect` signals from the OK and Cancel buttons on the popup to the `QEventLoop.quit` slot.

I could not get this to work, as it appeared that the `QEventLoop` was completely bypassed immediately. So I tried with just a yellow button that shows in the top left corner, and when it is clicked it should exit the `QEventLoop`, and then then turn red, which still does't work:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self,parent=None,*args,**kwargs):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent,*args,**kwargs)

    self._webEngine = QWebEngineView(self)
    self._webEngine.setPage(MyWebEnginePage(self._webEngine))
    self._webEngine.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/javascript-alert-box-demo.html"))

    self.setCentralWidget(self._webEngine)

    self.showMaximized()

class MyWebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):
  def __init__(self,parent,*args,**kwargs):
    QWebEnginePage.__init__(self,parent,*args,**kwargs)

  def javaScriptConfirm(self,url,msg):
    print("in here")
    button = QPushButton(self.parent().window())
    button.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow")
    button.show()

    loop = QEventLoop(self.parent().window())
    button.clicked.connect(loop.quit)
    loop.exec_()

    button.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")

def myExceptHook(e,v,t):
  sys.__excepthook__(e,v,t)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  sys.excepthook = myExceptHook
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  window = MainWindow()
  app.quit()
```

When the program runs, it navigates to `https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/javascript-alert-box-demo.html`, and I click on the button that brings up the JS confirm box (2nd button down). In the corner of the screen, a red button shows. It should be yellow, and only turn red once I click it, but the `QEventLoop` never loops, it is exited from immediately. When I can get the button to stay yellow until clicked, I can then remove it and connect the popup buttons to the `QEventLoop.quit` slot.

I have tried making the `loop` variable a `self.loop`, different parent objects for the `QEventLoop`, making the `button` a `self.button`, I'm not sure why the loop quits straight away. What do I need to change in order for the `QEventLoop` to actually loop?

Comment: Why do you use app.quit()t? In what environment are you running the application? I changed app.quit() to app.exec_() and I don't reproduce your problem on the terminal

Comment: I didnt know there was a different between .exec_ and .quit; am running in the normal Python IDLE, will test the .exec_ this evening.

Comment: do not use IDLE, since in production you will not manage that environment, use the terminal or CMD. Also read the docs